# Ionic 3 - modal backdrop does not work

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, modalviewcontroller

I want my modal pops up (with backdrop) rather than a new page. I followed some tutorials but the backdrop is not working (it should be activated by default). I am sure I am missing something.

### Here the code from the page where the modal is opened.

```
openPhonesModal(){
const myModalOptions: ModalOptions = {
  showBackdrop: true,
  enableBackdropDismiss: false
};
const myModalData = {
phone1: '01 239 239',
phone2: '901 200 438'
};
const myModal: Modal = this.modal.create('ModalseephonesPage',{phones: 
myModalData},myModalOptions);
myModal.present();
}
```

### Here the code of the modal itself:

```
export class ModalseephonesPage {
constructor(private navParams: NavParams, private view: ViewController) {
}
ionViewWillLoad() {
const phones = this.navParams.get(‘phones’);
console.log(phones);
} 
closeModal(){
this.view.dismiss();
}
}
```

I hope I provided enough information. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you mention the modal taking you to a new page, do you mean the modal shows up in full screen? If so, that is due to the device's screen resolution. If, for example, you were to open the modal in a desktop browser environment (or even the device in landscape mode), would it behave the way you want it to?

Comment: Set  `enableBackdropDismiss`  to `true`

Comment: @Gabriel. yes, I want my model to be like in a desktop browser (not full screen)

Comment: @Duannx, it did not work as it is to dismiss the modal by clicking on the back. I do not want the modal is opened in full screen but a modal like in a web browser.

Comment: Ionic modal will show in full screen in small device. In tablet or desktop, you will see modal show in center and have backdrop to touch. If you want show modal like pop up in small device you need to format it by CSS